# Ansible complex data manipulation on hostvars

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I am trying here to show my problem with an example, I have the hostvars facts setup like below:

my ansible hostgroup : `app_group = ["hostname-a", "hostname-b", "hostname-c", "hostname-d"]`

```
hostname-a:
    action_list:
        start: ["service-A": "jar example-a.jar]
        stop: []
        
hostname-b:
    action_list:
        start: []
        stop: ["service-B]
        
hostname-c:
    action_list:
        start: ["service-X": "jar example-x.jar]
        stop: []
        
hostname-d:
    action_list:
        start: ["service-Y": "jar example-y.jar]
        stop: []
```

I need to build a variable, that has comprehensive list of service names

```
final_start_service_list: ["service-A", "service-X", "service-Y"]
```

I tried something like below, but not working..

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups["app_group"] | map('extract', hostvars) | map(attribute='action_list') | flatten| map(attribute='start')| default([]) | flatten | default([]) }}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You get an error? In that case which one? Did you try to execute your expression step-by-step (with only the `map` filter, then add the second one, ...) to check you get the expected result at every step? BTW, the `map` can be combined in `map('extract', hostvars, 'action_list.start')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*lookup* [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables) is what you need, I think, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: hostname_a,hostname_b,hostname_c,hostname_d
  vars:
    hostname_a:
      action_list:
        start: ["service-A": "jar example-a.jar"]
        stop: []
    hostname_b:
      action_list:
        start: []
        stop: ["service-B"]
    hostname_c:
      action_list:
        start: ["service-X": "jar example-x.jar"]
        stop: []
    hostname_d:
      action_list:
        start: ["service-Y": "jar example-y.jar"]
        stop: []
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        final_start_service_list: "{{ final_start_service_list|default([]) +
                                      _start.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      vars:
        _var: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
        _start: "{{ _var.action_list.start.0|default('') }}"
      when: _start|length > 0
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: final_start_service_list
      run_once: true
```

does the job

```yaml
  final_start_service_list:
  - service-A
  - service-X
  - service-Y
```